# Problema com múltiplos formulários na mesma página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estava querendo utilizar um script para vários formulários, mas não estou conseguindo. Sendo assim eu estou gerando um script para cada form com IDs únicos para cada campo e formulário.

Não estou conseguindo inibir o comportamento do formulário, toda vez que eu clico no botão de *submit* a página e recarregada.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Teste ajax jquery tutsmais</title>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
   return false;
   $.ajax({
      type      : 'post',
      url       : 't2.php',
      data      : '&nome=' + $('#nome1').val() + '&sobrenome=' + $('#sobrenome1').val(),
      dataType  : 'html',
      success : function(txt){
         $('#div1').html(txt);
      }
   });
});
</script>
<script>
$("#form2").submit(function(e){
   return false;
   $.ajax({
      type      : 'post',
      url       : 't2.php',
      data      : '&nome=' + $('#nome2').val() + '&sobrenome=' + $('#sobrenome2').val(),
      dataType  : 'html',
      success : function(txt){
         $('#div2').html(txt);
      }
   });
});
</script>
<script>
$("#form3").submit(function(e){
   return false;
   $.ajax({
      type      : 'post',
      url       : 't2.php',
      data      : '&nome=' + $('#nome3').val() + '&sobrenome=' + $('#sobrenome3').val(),
      dataType  : 'html',
      success : function(txt){
         $('#div3').html(txt);
      }
   });
});
</script>
<script>
$("#form4").submit(function(e){
   return false;
   $.ajax({
      type      : 'post',
      url       : 't2.php',
      data      : '&nome=' + $('#nome4').val() + '&sobrenome=' + $('#sobrenome4').val(),
      dataType  : 'html',
      success : function(txt){
         $('#div4').html(txt);
      }
   });
});
</script>
<script>
$("#form5").submit(function(e){
   return false;
   $.ajax({
      type      : 'post',
      url       : 't2.php',
      data      : '&nome=' + $('#nome5').val() + '&sobrenome=' + $('#sobrenome5').val(),
      dataType  : 'html',
      success : function(txt){
         $('#div5').html(txt);
      }
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1">
   </div>
   <h2>form via ajax</h2>
   <form id="form1">
      Digite seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome1"><br>
      Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" id="sobrenome1"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="id1"><br>
   </form>
   <div id="div2">
   </div>
   <h2>form via ajax</h2>
   <form id="form2">
      Digite seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome2"><br>
      Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" id="sobrenome2"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="id2"><br>
   </form>
   <div id="div3">
   </div>
   <h2>form via ajax</h2>
   <form id="form3">
      Digite seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome3"><br>
      Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" id="sobrenome3"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="id3"><br>
   </form>
   <div id="div4">
   </div>
   <h2>form via ajax</h2>
   <form id="form4">
      Digite seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome4"><br>
      Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" id="sobrenome4"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="id4"><br>
   </form>
   <div id="div5">
   </div>
   <h2>form via ajax</h2>
      <form id="form5">
      Digite seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome5"><br>
      Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" id="sobrenome5"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="id5"><br>
   </form>
   <p></p>
</body></html>
```

O outro problema que eu estava encontrando antes de fazer essa alteração era que, usando os campos e o botão submit fora do formulário, ao clicar em qualquer botão submit da página estavam sendo enviados todos os campos.

Comment: Se tivéssemos o html até te podíamos ajudar a por um script para vários formulários :)

Comment: Olá eu tentei colocar o código todo agora. Ta aparecendo meio estranho, mas acho que depois vai aparecer normal. Caso não aparece eu vou tentar colar novamente.

Comment: @ViníciusJoséMoreira editei seu código para ficar minimamente organizado. Quando for postar código, lembre-se ou de colocar 4 espaços a mais no começo das linhas para o sistema do site formatar corretamente, ou selecionar o trecho de código e apertar o botão `{ }` na barra de formatação, que os espaços a mais serão adicionados.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar uma `class` ao butão de enviar, trocar o seu tipo para `button` invés de submit - depois disso, fazes um bind ao click nesse elemento para serializar os inputs que pertencem a esse formulario. ainda nesse elemento, metes um data-attribute com um selector para onde queres que o html vá quando retornar:

```
$(function(){
    $('.enviar').on('click',function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
      url: 't2.php',
      data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
      if (that.attr('data-landing-element')) {
        $(that.attr('data-landing-element')).html(data);
      }
      }
    })
  });
});

<h2>form via ajax</h2>
<form id="form1">
  Digite seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome1"><br>
  Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" name="sobrenome1"><br>
  <input type="submit" class="enviar" data-landing-element="#div2"><br>
</form>

<h2>form via ajax</h2>
<form id="form2">
  Digite seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome2"><br>
  Digite seu sobrenome: <input type="text" name="sobrenome2"><br>
  <input type="button" class="enviar" data-landing-element="#div2"><br>
</form>

<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

ps: é tarde e não testei o codigo, mas a ideia está lá :)

Comment: Agradeço funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @ViníciusJoséMoreira marque a resposta como certa, então :)